# Datalist not displaying items ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a serious problem with data list I HATE IT so much. I have a list of data that displays cart items in a table.. basic right?

Sure, but not for data list! its like data list says I MUST DESTROY YOU. The data list does not show any items that I should display!

Here are some screenshots that will let you understand my issue here.

[image: live example for the problem]

[image: from visual studio it shows items]

So basically the items are displayed in VS, but in the web application it doesn't.

PLEASE HELP :(

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container-sm cart-page">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>المنتج</th>
            <th>الكمية</th>
            <th>السعر الفرعي</th>
        </tr>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="cart-info">
                            <img src="http://bestjquery.com/tutorial/product-grid/demo8/images/img-1.jpg" alt="camera">
                            <div>
                                <p>Camera 211</p>
                                <small>السعر: 50 ر.س.</small>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#">حذف</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10"></td>
                    <td>50 ر.س.</td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </table>
    <div class="total-price">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="titles">السعر الفرعي</td>
                <td>150 ر.س.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="titles">VAT</td>
                <td>22.50 ر.س.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="titles">المجموع</td>
                <td>172.50 ر.س.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="store.aspx">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-continue-shopping">إكمال التسوق</button>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="checkout.aspx">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-checkout">إكمال الدفع</button>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fun fact: **you don't need to use `DataList`** - you can just render items directly.

Comment: You haven't posted any code that shows you setting `DataList1.DataSource` nor calling `DataBind()`.

Comment: If you're not married to the datalist, I highly recommend you have a look at jQuery Datatables... I am using it currently to render grids and lists in a data-heavy application, and it's excellent, and free to use. Performance is impressive also. Url is datatables.net.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey **jQuery (and jQuery UI) needs to die**. It's ancient, unmaintained, and unnecessary (just google "you don't need jquery"). Anyway, even if the OP was going to use that instead of `<asp:DataList>` they still need to render their data to the page in the first place in order for jQuery or whatever to access it, which they are not doing at-present.

Comment: It's not that old (last update 9 months ago), but anyway who cares? The important part is that it works well, it's highly customizable, and it's free. To load data into it you just create a controller method and bind it through ajax.... Also your comment doesn't help anyone unless you provide an alternative...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DataSource` property with some list or table of data.

Here is a link to the MSDN article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.datasource?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_BaseDataList_DataSource

What is your data source? Are you using a database?

If you do not have a database you can mockup a dataset in XML, JSON, or CSV and then deserialize into your code.

I believe that you can bind anything that implements `IList`.